# Mock Object returned has all null fields causing test to fail

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, spock

I have a simple class that uses a service called ReportingService. It gets injected into the class and I am verifying that it is called and with the expected arguments. The mock, returns the ReportSummary object i want to assert in the tests, by ensuring reportType and the other values meet the expectations. Unfortunately, the ReportSummary fields are all null, what am i doing wrong?

```java
class ReportSummary {
   String reportType
   Date createdTime
   String reportedById 
}
```

```java
class ReportingService {
   ReportSummary updateReport(Report reportData) {
       ...
   }
}
```

This Service is injected into a class PricingService like this:

```java
   class PricingService {
       @Autowired
       ReportingService reportingService

       ReportingSummary updatePricingDetails( ReportData data) {
           reportingService.updateReport(data)
       }
  }
```

The class is used in the service like this

```java
class PricingServiceSpec extends Specification {

   ReportingService reportingService = Mock()
   PricingService pricingService = new PricingService( reportingService)
   ReportData  data = new ReportData(........)       

   def "Should return summary report data" (){
     given:       
     Date today = new Date (System.currentMillis())

     ReportSummary summary = new ReportSummary(reportType: 'Pricing',createdTime:           
     today, reportedById: 'GXT111111345')
  
     when:
  
     ReportSummary response = pricingService.updatePricingDetails(data)

     then:
     1 * reportingService.updateReport( data : {
   
     assert it.pricingDescription == 'Pricing for Produce'
  
     }) >> summary
  
     response.reportType == 'Pricing'  // The reportType is null why?
     response.reportedById == 'GXT111111345'   // The reportById is null, why? The 
     0 * _       
    )       
   }
 }
```

Comment: In your example code, there are incomplete classes, missing classes (`Report`, `ReportData`), seemingly conflicting type names (`ReportSummary` vs. `ReportingSummary`), contradictory types vs. parameter names (`updateReport(Report reportData)`). Hence, I cannot run your code, but also cannot do an analysis on paper based on pseudo code which might not reflect the real situation. Please edit the question and turn it into an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Ideally, publish the MCVE project on GitHub. Then everyone can reproduce the problem and help you fix it.

Comment: This question is a mess of pseudo code. Missing constructors (or Groovy constructor calls with named parameters instead), `currentMillis()` instead of `currentTimeMillis()` and several other name mismatches I did not even mention before. Do you ever test your code before you post questions? This stuff does not even compile for so many reasons. You are an experienced user with 900 reputation points and 131 questions asked here before. How can you still not know how to ask a question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some example code which at least compiles and kind of emulates your situation, even though it returns some dummy data (but at least different from the stub result you want to test):

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q67912725

class ReportData {
  String pricingDescription;
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q67912725

class ReportSummary {
  String reportType
  Date createdTime
  String reportedById
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q67912725

class ReportingService {
  ReportSummary updateReport(ReportData reportData) {
    return new ReportSummary(
      reportType: "real report",
      createdTime: new Date(),
      reportedById: "me"
    )
  }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q67912725

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired

class PricingService {
  @Autowired
  ReportingService reportingService

  ReportSummary updatePricingDetails(ReportData data) {
    reportingService.updateReport(data)
  }
}
```

Here is a passing test. Your basic problem was that you tried to use a method parameter name in a method constraint, i.e. in your original code the `data :` part before the asserting closure. Method arguments are matched by type and position, not by parameter name. Omit that, and you are fine.

BTW, you also should not use `assert` in the method parameter constraint, but a simple boolean expression. A failed assertion would make the test fail, which is not what you want. You simply want to match a parameter value.

Fixing the test was not so difficult for me. It took me 10 times longer to actually make this mess compile and do something logical in order to even begin to analyse the test.

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q67912725

import spock.lang.Specification

class PricingServiceTest extends Specification {
  def reportingService = Mock(ReportingService)
  def pricingService = new PricingService(reportingService: reportingService)
  def reportData = new ReportData(pricingDescription: 'Pricing for Produce')

  def "Should return summary report data"() {
    given:
    ReportSummary stubbedSummary = new ReportSummary(
      reportType: 'Pricing',
      createdTime: new Date(),
      reportedById: 'GXT111111345'
    )

    when:
    ReportSummary reportSummary = pricingService.updatePricingDetails(reportData)

    then:
    1 * reportingService.updateReport(
      { it.pricingDescription == 'Pricing for Produce' }
    ) >> stubbedSummary
    reportSummary.reportType == stubbedSummary.reportType
    reportSummary.reportedById == stubbedSummary.reportedById
    0 * _
  }
}
```

Comment: Oops, I just noticed that yesterday I had posted a duplicate of  `ReportingService` instead of `PricingService`. I just fixed that.